# MCMC with slowly varying Log-Likelihood

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, metropolis-hastings, likelihood

I am using MCMC (Metropolis-Hastings) to simulate values of $\theta$: I have a Log-likelihood (using 10 inputs $x_i$) 
$$L=-\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)^2$$
The variation over the outputs of my Likelihood is limited, even though the extreme outputs are in the range of 0 to 1, the range of the value being about 0.2-0.5.

If a Uniform prior is used as proposal, the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance ratio is generally high (0.8 or higher) no matter what the chosen value for the parameter $\theta$ is. This results in (almost) any selected point being accepted regardless of the $\sigma$ value being used for selecting new points. There is little to no guidance being provided by the use of Metropolis Hastings algorithm as all points are accepted.

So when the output of a likelihood shows little variation when changing the parameter value how can you ensure that MCMC will still be able to simulate the posterior distribution?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear; MCMC is a method for generating random numbers, not a method for optimization, which latter seems to be what you are trying to do based on "... determine the value of $\theta$".

Answer (score 1):

If the variations of the target $\pi(\theta|x)\propto f(x|\theta)$ are limited,

1. it means that the data is little informative about $\theta$; this is a poor situation from an inferential viewpoint.
2. it means that an MCMC algorithm like the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm will converge very fast since most proposals (from the Uniform prior) will be accepted; this is an ideal situation from a simulation viewpoint.

> However, I do not understand the part about $\sigma$, as this symbol
>   does not appear in the likelihood. Is this the scale of the Uniform
>   proposal? In which case this is no longer the prior and no longer a
>   valid proposal.